# Ember.js - Cannot render nested models

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Have an upcoming weekend project and using it to evaluate Ember.js and I cannot figure out why I cannot display nested objects in my template. This does not work:

```
{{#each emails}}
  {{email_address}}
{{/each}}
```

When I try just {{emails}} I get a hint that something is right:

Models:

```
App.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  company: DS.attr('string'),
  emails: DS.hasMany('App.Email')
});

App.Email = DS.Model.extend({
  contact: DS.belongsTo('App.Contact'),
  emailAddress: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Route:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('contacts', function() {
this.resource('contact', {path: ':contact_id'});
  });
});

App.ContactsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  init: function() {},
  model: function() {
    return App.Contact.find();
  }
});

App.ContactRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Contact.find(params.contact_id);
  }
});
```

I have no idea what to try next. I'm using active_model_serializer in Rails. I've tried embedding, side-loading to no avail. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `each` helper it's recomendable to be more specific about the items you are looping over to avoid such problems.

Try the following:

```
{{#each email in model.emails}}
  {{email.emailAddress}}
{{/each}}
```

This should also work:

```
{{#each emails}}
  {{this.emailAddress}}
{{/each}}
```

And also, your model property is called `emailAddress` and not `email_address`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Gave it a try and I'm still not having any luck. I think I need to examine the JSON a little more closely.

Comment: This answer got me on my way, but I had to include the emails in the result from the initial fetch of all contacts. Thanks for you help.